# Problem with port when launching ruby/rails app on windows10/ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ubuntu

I have two different projects - one that I made for practicing purpose and one that is a real project.

I'm using RVM to set version and they both run on 2.6.0 & rails 5.2.3

My practice project launches fine on localhost:3000. However I can't see anywhere or anyhow that it's being used while running the app (checking in resource manager/netstat)

However when I'm trying to launch the second app I'm getting "listen: Address already in use - listen(2) and rails shuts down.

I've tried restarting the terminal/my computer just to make sure nothing is running on port 3000 and I can't for the life of me understand why it's not working.

Has anyone experienced something similar? I've obviously tried looking at similar questions here however most answers are related to terminating whatever is running on 3000 at the moment, but I can't confirm that anything is.

UPDATED:
Ok so when I launch the app that complains about port being in use I get the following:

`/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems`

After that it tries to start, it says it's listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000 which is fine and dandy, but then it stops and here's the trace:

`` Traceback (most recent call last):
        19: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        18: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        17: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        15: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        14: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        13: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        12: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        11: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        10: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
         9: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
         8: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
         7: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
         6: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:73:in `run'
         5: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
         4: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:463:in `run'
         3: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:82:in `start_control'
         2: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `add_unix_listener'
         1: from /home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:328:in `add_unix_listener'
/home/sorgmantel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:328:in `listen': Address already in use - listen(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
Breadcrumb Mongo query succeeded meta_data collection:Array has been dropped for having an invalid data type ``

Is it possible that it has to do with file origins? My project runs fine because it's written in windows but I can't run the other one that was written on MAC, with the different line endings and all. I've heard Ruby can be sensitive when you run it on windows machines.

Comment: Have you tried `lsof -wni tcp:3000`? That should show you the processes running on that port (on ubuntu, at least).

Comment: Yes, I have. Nothing comes up, no matter what port I try. Well I tried without the "-wni" part

Comment: You say your practice project launched fine on localhost:3000 yet you can't see anywhere or anyhow that it's being used while running the app. How, exactly, does your practice project "launch"? Are you not running `rails s` or some equivalent in a terminal?

Comment: I can view the website in the browser at localhost:3000 but I can't see that the port is being used. Yes I start them both using rails s and they're both configured to run on that port. I'm not trying to run them simultaneously, it's just that one works and the other one doesn't. I can post some screenshots if that will help.

Comment: Generally copy and pasted output are preferred over screenshots, but it's your call. Sometimes screenshots make sense.

Comment: I have updated the post with more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparantly this was caused by

`activate_control_app`

in my puma.rb file. When I commented it out the app launched fine.